unable to deploy web application in Azure
I am new to Azure and I am experiencing this issue when trying to deploy my Flask web application using Azure CLi. It stucks and the error is like this:
Deployment failed because the site failed to start within 10 mins.
Does it mean there are anything wrong in my code? I deploy the zip direcotry and free configurations.

I tried a lot of times and I wonder what should I do next to fix it....

Is it default flask application? If not, please provide your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Some of the containers need more than 230 seconds to start, to override the default timeout, add the WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT app setting in the App Service=>Environment Variables. This setting can be set to a maximum of 1800 seconds.


Use the az webapp up command, it automatically creates the resources and deploys your application to Azure.

I have created a flask application and deployed to Azure using the command az webapp up.
(.venv) C:\Users\uname\flask-webapp>az webapp up

D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py:17: UserWarning: You are using cryptography on a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows Operating System. Cryptography will be significantly faster if you switch to using a 64-bit Python.
The webapp 'red-river-145465b3ce2c484285d594bf91da3c15' doesn't exist
Creating Resource group 'XXXXX_rg_8529' ...
Resource group creation complete
Creating AppServicePlan 'XXXXX_asp_2978' or Updating if already exists
Readonly attribute name will be ignored in class <class 'azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.models._models_py3.AppServicePlan'>
Creating webapp 'red-river-145465b3XXXXXd594bf91da3c15' ...
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Creating zip with contents of dir C:\Users\uname\flask-webapp ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
Polling the status of async deployment. Start Time: 2024-06-01 11:25:34.336292+00:00 UTC
Status: Received build request... Time: 2(s)
Status: Received build request... Time: 21(s)
Status: Build successful. Time: 38(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 55(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 73(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 90(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 112(s)
Status: Starting the site... Time: 130(s)
Status: Site started successfully. Time: 147(s)
You can launch the app at http://red-river-145465b3ce2c4XXXXX94bf91da3c15.azurewebsites.net
Setting 'az webapp up' default arguments for current directory. Manage defaults with 'az configure --scope local'
--resource-group/-g default: XXXXX_rg_8529
--sku default: P1V2
--plan/-p default: XXXXX_asp_2978
--location/-l default: eastus
--name/-n default: red-river-145465b3XXXXX285d594bf91da3c15
{
  "URL": "http://red-river-145465b3ce2c484285dXXXXXa3c15.azurewebsites.net",
  "appserviceplan": "XXXXXr_asp_2978",
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "red-river-145465b3ce2c484285d594bf91da3c15",
  "os": "Linux",
  "resourcegroup": "XXXXX_rg_8529",
  "runtime_version": "python|3.10",
  "runtime_version_detected": "-",
  "sku": "PREMIUMV2",
  "src_path": "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\flask-webapp"
}


Able to run the flask deployed application.


